# Creating a Pseudo Code and Diagram from C# Program

Tags: c#, diagram, pseudocode, flow-diagram

I have developed an application which is used to parse user utterances for the extraction of relevant information stored in the database.

The developed application has been purely developed using C# and consists of few functions, procedures etc.

I have been asked to produce Pseudo Code and Pseudo diagram for it to be used in the report for others to understand the flow of the developed application.

I am currently looking for a tool or software, which can help in producing above (especially Pseudo Code), as at the minute it seems a huge exploration of the code.

The type of code I am having to create of developed is as follow: 
[image]

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford to buy it, I recommend [AthTek's flowchart to code](http://www.athtek.com/flowchart-to-code.html). Its got a nice UI and its easy to use and it will generate pseudo code for a variety of languages, including C#, based on the flowchart.

Another good one, especially if you would like to have Visual Studio integration is [Code Rocket](http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com/Products/CodeRocketForVisualStudio). It integrates directly within Visual Studio and you can edit your flowchart or your pseudocode and both views stay in sync. It is great and its a little cheaper then AthTek!

If you need something free, try out [DRAKON Editor](http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/). It's interface is not as intuitive as AthTek's software and it has a little more of a steeper learning curve and it does require [ActiveTcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads) to use, but it is free! Here is a [PDF Tutorial](http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/csharp.pdf) to get you up and going with C# using DRAKON Editor.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [NClass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/) for generating diagrams. It is a free tool that generates UML diagrams. I do not know of any programs for automatically generating pseudocode though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I believe it will solve half of my problem which is creating a flow diagram. Any idea related to the picture I have just inserted in my question ?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible you could reverse engineer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28441/Pseudo-Code-Modeling-Language) project to get the pseudo code generator that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I believe it will solve half of my problem which is creating a flow diagram. Any idea related to the picture I have just inserted in my question ?